# Rails 3.2.3 JavaScript suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm not sure how or why this happened, but if anyone could suggest a course of action, I'd really appreciate it. Is there anything I can type into the console to figure out why it's not working? I've tried 'bundle update' a few times and restarted my server, but nothing's working.

Comment: Have you tried another browser?  Also, what errors are you getting in your JavaScript console (FF, Chrome, Safari)?

Comment: omg you're the best! i checked my console and found an error in one of my XXXXXXX.js.coffee files. After removing the bad code, my js started working!

Comment: We should close this. There's nothing in this question that will ever help anyone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out what was wrong: I had a coffeescript error in one of my XXXXXXX.js.coffee files. I found out this was the problem by reloading the page with chrome's javascript console open. It logged an error and called out the file. I opened the file and fixed the error.