# Rails app javascript stopped working in production works perfectly in development

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, production-environment

None of my javascript seems to work in production.

Unfortunately those questions:
[JavaScript not working in Rails app in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778847/javascript-not-working-in-rails-app-in-production)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470207/rails-javascript-working-in-development-but-not-in-production
[Rails JavaScript views not working in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926034/rails-javascript-views-not-working-in-production)
[Rails 3.2.3 JavaScript suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055240/rails-3-2-3-javascript-suddenly-stopped-working)
are either unanswered or the solutions don't help.

In the development environment all my JS is working absolutely fine. However on production even simple stuff I made myself isn't working (I'm using a bootstrap template with a lot of included JS there).

The only error I receive is this one

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
angular.module("app",[require("./home").name]);
```

But it shouldn't affect the rest of the javascript. Here the environment/production.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = true
  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb
```

I tried to set compile to true, it didn't help.

This is what I put in initializers/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css *.scss *.coffee )
```

Didn't help either.

I run rake assets:precompile manually (although my capistrano puma script does it too:

```
DEBUG [b487d8df] Command: cd /home/deploy/apps/mosflash/releases/20150924201201 && ( RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
```

Can someone hint me into the right direction?

Comment: Did you define your app as an Angular app in your application layout. For example: <html ng-app = "exampleApp">

Comment: No I did not, I am barely aware what Angular is (it's a bought template, not one I made myself). You think this might be the source of my problem? In development mode everything worked fine...

Comment: Strangely enough by deleting the corresponding line I was able to run everything smoothly in production. Didn't assume the error would be that important! Should someone encounter the same error - the template is "Minimal - responsive e-commerce Theme" where you need to delete this line in main.js:
`angular.module("app",[require("./home").name]);`